# Wordpress : How to make User meta value unique?

Tags: wordpress, unique

I have added a user contact number in the WP user_meta table with meta_key `contact` . Now I want that meta key value to be *unique*. How to achieve this?

Comment: You'll have to enforce that by validating the information when it is changed.

Comment: Means ?? how ?? I didn't get this.

Comment: Is that data entered in the backend or the front end (and saved via some plugin / custom code)?

Comment: When you insert meta value, check existence of meta value with code like this: $checkMeta=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='contact' AND meta_value=".$yourValue,ARRAY_A);

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is as follows:

1. Get all users that have the desired meta_key using the function [get_users()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/).
2. Store the IDs of all the users obtained in step 1 in an array.
3. Use the [get_metadata](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/) function inside a `foreach` loop to retrieve the values of the metadata field and store them in an array.
4. Check if a particular value is in the array before adding it as a meta value.

Each of these steps is illustrated below, using "m520_contact" as the meta key (since it's recommended to [always prefix everything in your WP code](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/best-practices/#prefix-everything)).

**Step 1**

```
//Get all users with the desired meta key
$users = get_users(array('meta_key' => 'm520_contact'));
```

**Step 2**

```
// Store the IDs of all the users obtained in step 1 in an array.
$user_ids = [];
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    array_push($user_ids, $user->data->ID);
}
```

**Step 3**

```
/**
*
* Use get_metadata() to retrieve
the values of the metadata field. 
*
* get_metadata() returns an array,
so we're using array_shift to
store the returned value as a string.
*
* We'll store the retrieved values
in a variable called $all_meta_values.
*/

$all_meta_values = [];

foreach ($user_ids as $user_id) {
    array_push(
        $all_meta_values,
        array_shift(
            get_metadata(
                'user',
                $user_id, 'm520_contact'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

**Step 4**

You can store your check in a function for reusability. Something like this for example:

```
/**
* Checks if a value is in the array (unique) before adding it as a meta value.
*/
function m520_is_value_unique(int|string $needle, array $haystack) : bool {
    return in_array($needle, $haystack) ? false : true;
}
```

Then you could use the function each time before calling `add_user_meta()` or `update_user_meta()`. For instance:

```
if (m520_is_value_unique($new_contact_number, $all_meta_values)) {
    add_user_meta(1, 'm520_contact', 1300400500);
}
```

HTH, Mwale